# Como aplicar filtros (queryset) com "models.ForeignKey" no Django

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-filter

**Olá, Pessoal!**

Estou ingressando no Django e estou com dificuldades para aplicar um filtro (queryset - models.ForeignKey) para selecionar apenas alguns registros para apresentação no combo de chave estrangeira, meu código é bem simples:

[image: models.py]

Eu gostaria de limitar a apresentação no combo em destaque (company) no form "rates" apenas para alguns id´s:

[image: formulário "Rates"]

Gostaria que **fossem apresentados ao usuário somente a Bandeirantes e a Globosat (company_id = 3 e 4)**.
Sei que dá para fazer isso diretamente no modelo através do *"limit_choices_to", mas não posso utilizar este recurso*, visto que preciso restringir os registros de acordo com um campo do cadastro do usuário, este exemplo é apenas para ilustrar um problema que estou tendo em uma aplicação que estou desenvolvendo.

Até cheguei a configurar um form, mas não avancei:

[image: form]

No que diz respeito a view, configurei apenas a "index":

[image: view]

Segue os códigos, models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Rate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    comentario = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Rate


class RateModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Rate
        fields = "__all__"
```

views:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Olá, MUNDO!")
```

Desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Amigo, por favor, compartilhe o código como texto, e não como imagem...

Comment: Ok, está feito!

Comment: Resolvi este impasse através desta contribuição: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179129/filter-foreignkey-field-in-django-admin

Answer (score -1):

Olá vc já tentou o filter(), para os campos que você quer mostrar.
Exemplo de uso:
https://www.w3schools.com/django/django_queryset_filter.php

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).